# So I tried solving a problem in Python, and I actually did it. But how do I translate this to C++?

Tags: python, c++

so this is the code I want to translate. I do know C++ but I dont know how to take an list of integars or how to use the map function in C++

This is the question of the solution/code:
An array A of length N is said to be pseudo-sorted if it can be made non-decreasing after performing the following operation at most once.

Choose an i such that 1≤i≤N−1 and swap Ai and Ai+1
Given an array A, determine if it is pseudo-sorted or not.

Input Format
The first line contains a single integer T - the number of test cases. Then the test cases follow.
The first line of each test case contains an integer N - the size of the array A.
The second line of each test case contains N space-separated integers A1,A2,…,AN denoting the array A.
Output Format
For each testcase, output YES if the array A is pseudo-sorted, NO otherwise.

You may print each character of YES and NO in uppercase or lowercase (for example, yes, yEs, Yes will be considered identical).

```
t = int(input())
    for b in range(t):
        e = int(input())
        a = list(map(int,input().split()))
        if e<3:
            print("YES")
        else:
            rs = True
            for i in range(e-1):
                if a[i]>a[i+1]:
                    f = a[i]
                    s = a[i + 1]
                    a[i]=s
                    a[i+1] =f
                    j = i+1
                    for j in range(e-1):
                        if a[j]>a[j+1]:
                            rs = False
                            break
            if rs==True:
                print("YES")
            else:
                print("NO")
```

Comment: std::vector<int> and std::transform, respectively

Comment: Learn C++ and it's data handling structures, classes, that is the way to get your program working. knowing just the equivalent classes/types/functions not going to get you there.

Comment: C++ doesn't have a map function. However, if you look at the Python documentation, what it does will be fully explained (with examples) and you just have to translate that to C++. Also, what does this code actually do?